# Images not drawing in eclipse

Tags: java, image, debugging, exception

I like pie I have a `BufferedImage space;` and I then try to initialize it by using the try-catch

```
try {
    space = ImageIO.read(new File("simple-star-space-background-effect-footage-023768280_prevstill.jpg"));
}
catch(Exception e) {}
```

When I try using `g.drawImage(space, 0, 0, 800, 600, null);` It doesn't show up. I think it has something to do with Eclipse because when I used a basic text editor, it worked. Here is a screenshot of where my pics are relevant to the program. They are in the same directory "src" but no image shows up.

[The Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSVth.png)

Comment: Is there an error that is caught by the try-catch statement?

Comment: Is your code in SpaceCombat.java class?

Comment: ya there is @jeremyms

Comment: what does it say?

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @RohunAgrawal you need to post the error for us to help you with the issue

Comment: @SyedBaryalay it says:

Comment: javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
 at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1301)
 at SpaceCombat.run(SpaceCombat.java:34)
 at SpaceCombat.main(SpaceCombat.java:27)

Comment: @RohunAgrawal have you read my below answer and have you tested the code?

Answer (score 0):

Please use:

```
try {
    File myImage = new File("simple-star-space-background-effect-footage-023768280_prevstill.jpg")
    System.out.println(myImage.getAbsolutePath());
    space = ImageIO.read(myImage);
} catch(Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I assume your path to your image is not correct, since you expect to have it in your user.dir system-property.
Also you eat the exception, which causes you to not see what the root cause of your issue is.

Also my hint is to avoid inline code. Define variables, which can be much easier debugged in the eclipse debugger instead of a single long line, which does multiple executions (like your new File(...) inlined in reading the image)